# Rails 4 + mongodb + activeadmin

Tags: mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I want to add activeadmin with my rails app that have mongodb database. I configure activeadmin compeletly but when I add other resource using command

```
 rails generate active_admin:resource Activity activity_name:string
```

It configure Activity on admin side but when clicked on Activities link it give error

```
undefined method `column_names' for Activity:Class
```

undefined method `column_names' for Activity:Class

```
            Rails.root: /home/tps/sites/coachup

            Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
            /home/tps/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@couchup/bundler/gems/active_admin-5b7fa25b1e0d/lib/active_admin/resource.rb:99:in `resource_column_names'
            /home/tps/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@couchup/bundler/gems/active_admin-5b7fa25b1e0d/lib/active_admin/order_clause.rb:19:in `to_sql'
            /home/tps/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@couchup/bundler/gems/active_admin-5b7fa25b1e0d/lib/active_admin/resource_controller/data_access.rb:216:in `apply_sorting'
            /home/tps/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@couchup/bundler/gems/active_admin-5b7fa25b1e0d/lib/active_admin/resource_controller/data_access.rb:51:in `find_collection'
            /home/tps/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@couchup/bundler/gems/active_admin-5b7fa25b1e0d/lib/active_admin/resource_controller/data_access.rb:34:in `collection'
            inherited_resources (1.4.1) lib/inherited_resources/actions.rb:7:in `index'
            actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
            actionpack (4.0.3) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
            actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
            actionpack (4.0.3) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
            activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:443:in `_run__778977280__process_action__callbacks'
            activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
            actionpack (4.0.3) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
            actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
            actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
            activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
            activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
            activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
            actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
            actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:245:in `process_action'
            actionpack (4.0.3) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
            actionpack (4.0.3) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
            actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
            actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
            actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
            actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `call'
            actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
            actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
            actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
            actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
            actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
            actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:680:in `call'
            warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
            warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
            warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
            rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
            rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
            rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
            actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
            actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in `call'
            rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
            rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
            actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'
            actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I was under the impression that `ActiveAdmin` only works with `ActiveRecord`.

Maybe you should try the [ActiveAdmin-Mongoid](https://github.com/elia/activeadmin-mongoid) gem.

Comment: If it is a rails 4 specific question, you should update the tag to `ruby-on-rails-4`. Anyway I think the first part of the answer is valid.